# updating on a csv file using python

Tags: python, csv, io

I am working on a small project,where one of the step is to write on a csv file a list of data.
I am looping through  a list,and fetching specific data and writing it to a csv.
The problem is when the write operation is being processed it removes previous entries of the csv file.My csv writing method is as follows:
and an example

```
def csv_writer(data_list,file_path):
    import csv
    file_p = open(file_path, "wb")
    write_pattern = csv.writer(file_p, delimiter=",", quotechar=",")
    write_pattern.writerow(data_list)
    file_p.close()
```

An example data list is:

```
data_list = ['a', '', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'e']
```

And I am trying to have data in the file as follows:

```
a,,a,d,e
a,b,c,d,e
a,g.j,l,m
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Python documentation to the rescue! http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Please, rephrase your sentence in order that it is understandable: _" my goal is to every data_list that is returned from the loop"_ From your exemple, I understand that you want to insert data_list BEFORE all the content of the file. If not so, it means that you will have to do efforts to express your questions in understandable way

Comment: @eyquem I have changed it,hope it express the problem well :)

Comment: No, there is still ambiguity if the exemple means that you want to insert data_list BEFORE or AFTER the existing content

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe open the file in append mode?

```
file_p = open(file_path, "ab")
```

Comment: it works!thanks alot,I was searching for this mode but unfortunately missed it, at last thought,I will have to custom method for this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the file, try opening it for appending, like this.

```
def csv_writer(data_list,file_path):
    import csv
    file_p = open(file_path, "a")
    write_pattern = csv.writer(file_p, delimiter=",", quotechar=",")
    write_pattern.writerow(data_list)
    file_p.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

**delimiter** and **quotechar** must preferably be choosen as different

As I understood the question, the aim is to insert a new line before all the content of a CSV file. Here's the code to do that:

```
import csv

def csv_writer(data_list,file_path):
    file_p = open(file_path, "rb+")
    reader_pattern = csv.reader(file_p, delimiter=",", quotechar="$")
    write_pattern = csv.writer(file_p, delimiter=",", quotechar="$")

    content = list(reader_pattern)

    file_p.seek(0,0)
    write_pattern.writerow(data_list)
    write_pattern.writerows(content)
    file_p.truncate()
    file_p.close()


data_list = ['a', '', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'e']


csv_writer(data_list,'Copie de zozou.txt')
```